# Как держать кнопку "еще" в правом нижнем углу текста?

Tags: html, css

[image]

Не могу понять как прибить кнопку "ещё" в правом нижнем углу от текста. До и после клика по нему. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, ничего не могу придумать :(

Comment: откуда нам знать что вы там намудрили? мы тут не эксперты в чтении мыслей

Comment: Добавьте HTML и CSS код вашей страницы, а не скриншот.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.block {
   width: 300px;
   border: 1px solid red;
}

.more {
float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
<span class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In, libero quia blanditiis ex explicabo sunt. Laudantium, itaque quaerat! Fuga fugit iure distinctio nobis cum, adipisci dolores excepturi aliquid? Debitis!
</span>
<span class="more">еще</span>
</div>

<div class="block">
<span class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio excepturi corporis optio. Modi cumque, quod cum sunt alias quas maiores ab ex in eum. Commodi eligendi perspiciatis?
</span>
<span class="more">еще</span>
</div>
```